# How can i run hector navigation for exploration?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, exploration, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i run hector navigation?
I run urg_node and hector_slam but i don't know how can i run hector navigation for exploration.I searched very much but i can't find anything...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112576/how-can-i-run-hector-navigation-for-exploration?/) by [mr.karimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9676/mr.karimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I found the answer!

you can find hector_navigation here :

[https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation]

after download it , make it:

```
rosmake  hector_navigation_master
```

after that you need a launch file

nav.launch:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="hector_costmap" type="hector_costmap" name="hector_costmap" output="screen" respawn="false">
    <param name="cost_map_topic" value="cost_map" />
    <param name="map_frame_id" value="map" />
    <param name="local_transform_frame_id" value="base_footprint" />
    <param name="initial_free_cells_radius" value="0.3" />
    <param name="update_radius" value="4.0"/>
    <param name="costmap_pub_freq" value="4.0" />
    <param name="sys_msg_topic" value="syscommand" />

    <param name="use_grid_map" value="true" />
    <param name="grid_map_topic" value="scanmatcher_map" />

    <param name="use_elevation_map" value="true" />
    <param name="elevation_map_topic" value="elevation_map_local" />

    <param name="use_cloud_map" value="false" />
    <param name="cloud_topic" value="openni/depth/points" />

<!-- Not necessary to set, set by dynamic reconfigure -->
    <!--param name="max_delta_elevation" value="0.08"/-->
    <!--param name="allow_elevation_map_to_clear_occupied_cells" value="true" /-->
    <!--param name="max_clear_size" value="4" /-->
    <!--param name="slize_min_height" value="0.3" /-->
    <!--param name="slize_max_height" value="0.4" /-->
<!-- Not necessary to set, set by scanmatcher -->
    <!--param name="map_resolution" value="0.05" /-->
    <!--param name="max_grid_size_x" value="1024" /-->
    <!--param name="max_grid_size_y" value="1024" /-->
<!-- Not necessary to set, set by elvation_mapping -->
    <!-- param name="elevation_resolution" value="0.01" / -->
</node>

<node pkg="hector_driving_aid_markers" type="driving_aid_marker_node" name="hector_driving_aid_markers" output="screen">
    <param name="left_side_y_outer" value="0.205"/>
    <param name="left_side_y_inner" value="0.11"/>
    <param name="right_side_y_outer" value="-0.205"/>
    <param name="right_side_y_inner" value="-0.11"/>
</node>

<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="ElevationMapping" args="load hector_elevation_mapping/ElevationMapping openni_nodelet_manager" output="screen">
    <param name="elevation_resolution" value="0.01" />
    <param name="elevation_zero_level" value="16384" />
    <param name="min_observable_elevation" value="-1.0" />
    <param name="max_observable_elevation" value="0.5" />
    <param name="max_observable_distance" value="4.0" /> 
    <param name="sensor_variance" value="0.001" />   
    <param name="map_frame_id" value="map" />
    <param name="local_map_frame_id" value="base_stabilized" />
    <param name="local_elevation_map_topic" value="elevation_map_local" />
    <param name="gloabl_elevation_map_topic" value="elevation_map_global" />
    <param name="point_cloud_topic" value="openni/depth/points"/>
    <param name="grid_map_topic" value="scanmatcher_map"/>
    <param name="sys_msg_topic" value="syscommand" />
    <param name="publish_poseupdate" value="false" />
    <param name="poseupdate_pub_period" value="1.0" />
    <param name="poseupdate_height_covariance" value="0.25" />
    <param name="poseupdate_used_pattern_size" value="3" />
<!-- Not necessary to set, set by scanmatcher -->
    <!--param name="map_resolution" value="0.05" /-->
    <!--param name="max_grid_size_x" value="1024" /-->
    <!--param name="max_grid_size_y" value="1024" /-->
</node>

<node pkg="hector_elevation_mapping" type="ElevationMappingNode" name="ElevationMapping_1"  output="screen">
    <param name="elevation_resolution" value="0.01" />
    <param name="elevation_zero_level" value="16384" />
    <param name="min_observable_elevation" value="-1.0" />
    <param name="max_observable_elevation" value="0.5" />
    <param name="max_observable_distance" value="4.0" /> 
    <param name="sensor_variance" value="0.001" />   
    <param name="map_frame_id" value="map" />
    <param name="local_map_frame_id" value="base_stabilized" />
    <param name="local_elevation_map_topic" value="elevation_map_local" />
    <param name="gloabl_elevation_map_topic" value="elevation_map_global" />
    <param name="point_cloud_topic" value="openni/depth/points"/>
    <param name="grid_map_topic" value="scanmatcher_map"/>
    <param name="sys_msg_topic" value="syscommand" />
    <param name="publish_poseupdate" value="false" />
    <param name="poseupdate_pub_period" value="1.0" />
    <param name="poseupdate_height_covariance" value="0.25" />
    <param name="poseupdate_used_pattern_size" value="3" />
<!-- Not necessary to set, set by scanmatcher -->
    <!--param name="map_resolution" value="0.05" /-->
    <!--param name="max_grid_size_x" value="1024" /-->
    <!--param name="max_grid_size_y" value="1024" /-->
</node>

<node pkg="hector_elevation_visualization" type="hector_elevation_visualization" name="hector_elevation_visualization" output="screen" respawn="false">
    <param name="max_height_levels" value="10" />
    <param name="max_height" value="1.0" />
    <param name="elevation_map_frame_id" value="/elevation_map_local" />
    <param name="sys_msg_topic" value="/syscommand" />
</node>

<node pkg="hector_exploration_node" type="exploration_planner_node" name="hector_exploration_node" output="screen">

    <rosparam file="$(find hector_exploration_node)/config/costmap.yaml" command="load" />

</node>

</launch>
```

run this launch file and "hector_exploration_controller" node :

```
    roslaunch nav.launch
    rosrun hector_exploration_controller simple_exploration_controller
```

this node publish a cmd_vel message.

I think it isn't the best way for running hector_navigation and maybe i should change the launch file or run another nodes but it's not bad for First Answer!  :)

---

Originally posted by [mr.karimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9676/mr.karimi/) with karma: 52 on 2013-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-04**:
Hi, did you actually get results by running this package in this way? i installed and ran Hector_navigation and explorer nodes, but my robot just turns around itself (Z axis) without moving. whats your equipment? Thanks

**Comment by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on 2016-06-30**:
Hi I also wish to work with Hector Navigation. Can you please explain how the motors are setup and how they interact with the navigation?

**Comment by [orlando24](https://answers.ros.org/users/39490/orlando24/) on 2019-03-21**:
I know its been a very long time since you answered this question, but would you please provide a clearer little tutorial or update about how to run hector exploration? I would really appreciate your help here.

**Comment by [lukelu](https://answers.ros.org/users/56261/lukelu/) on 2020-09-10**:
We got the same issue in 2020, the issue is still not resolved. Hope to hear anyone who is able to make hector_navigation running.